# Symfony2: How to create Doctrine entities using a YAML file?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I want my Entity names to be different from the database table names (table names have a prefix that I don't want in entities. This is something I can not control. It's an existing big database).

For example, table name would be ab_product and I need the entity name to be just Product, not AbProduct.

To complicate things, I have few related tables all with this requirement (ab_order, ab_order_product etc).

In Symfony 1, I used to define all these mappings and relationships in a YAML file and then use one command to generate all the entity classes.

Is there a similar command in Symfony 2. I couldn't find one in "php app/console doctrine:generate" namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by specifying the table key in your entity

```
# src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.yml
Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    table: ab_product     <-------- This is what you are looking for
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
        price:
            type: decimal
            scale: 2
        description:
            type: text
```

You can also define the join column's name like so:

```
manyToOne:
        order:
            targetEntity: Order
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumn:
                name: ab_order
                referencedColumnName: id
```

You can find more here : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: I am fine with creating the YAML file (or multiple files as of Doctrine 2). What I couldn't find was a way to create the Entity classes (the PHP ones) from the YAML file.

Comment: I'm confused now. If you are looking for a way to generate it using the command line I don't think that's possible, however, you can generate the class pretending that your association are just basic attribute and edit the yaml file after that.

Comment: **I am looking for a way to generate entities using the command line**. I am confused why such a functionality does not exist since it's a common use case (of course I can think of creating something my own). This functionality exisited in version 1. There I would create a YAML file and maintain it as my mapping file. Whenever I need a change, I will first edit the YAML file and then recreate the PHP entity classes.

Comment: Again, I don't think you can, but if I'm proven wrong that would be good to know

Comment: You can simply run app/console doctrine:generate:entities; provided your mapping is alright then this will generate the entities together with basic getters and setters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cookbook entry about that: [How to Generate Entities from an Existing Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

As you already have your mapping data, you basicly just need to run `doctrine:generate:entities`.

Comment: I tried that command (and the rest in generate:) before posting the question. It tries to generate entities for all the database tables, and fail when it finds database tables that do not have primary keys (as I mentioned this is a DB that I do not have control. It has 400+ tables, some do not have primary keys). doctrine:generate:entities has a --filter option but that does not allow to filter tables, it's only for filtering entities. And I couldn't find a way to use it for my case (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: **update**. Sorry, I think the command I ran was doctrine:mapping:import, not this command. I will retry this command.